# Term for assessing unknown distribution

Tags: references, nonparametric, density-function, kernel-smoothing, definition

I come from the field of Numerical Analysis, and I look for the term which describes the problem of fitting a probability distribution to statistical numerical continuous data, without a-priori knowledge of the distribution.

Specifically, I read about nonparametric-statistics and in a lot of places it says that it best fit ordinal data (voting, categories, labels etc.), and not numerical.

What is the proper term I should be reading about? Am I wrong in this characterization of non-parametric statistics?

I should remark that I don't aim for the most precise definition, but rather the one that would allow me to contact people, ask questions and look for papers and textbooks.

Comment: You don't actually define nonparametric statistics anywhere that I see, so your question about being wrong in your definition seems odd -- but in truth many nonparametric methods are explicitly *designed* for numerical data and may require some adapting to use with ordinal data. If you want to learn about nonparametric stats, maybe start with a text. Conover's book (practical nonparametric statistics) - though it has been around a long time - is probably worth a look.

Comment: Thanks Glen. Are there any specific basic statistical concepts I should study before aiming at it?

Comment: I don't know what you have already. It doesn't really require much heavy machinery, but you need some probability, and a good handle on permutations and combinations and a little algebra. Some knowledge of the basics of hypothesis testing would be very useful.

Comment: Look into kernel density estimation